# What is the difference between "search" and "look up"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This questions is coming from [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56112/search-vs-look-up).

Is there any difference in meaning between the 2 terms?

Comment: To my ear, "search" sounds a lot more fastidious than "look up." You look up a word/number/quote in an indexed book (dictionary, phone book, etc.), but you search a novel/Google for a quote, etc.

Comment: You can also search this site to look up an answer. But you can't look up this site to search an answer. So they are quite obviously completely different things.

Comment: I looked up the whole house for my car keys!

Comment: I think I have some comments to make (maybe an answer even) -- (it's pretty simple, actually), but I am waiting for the OP share their (OR) original research as required.

Comment: You look up a word in the dictionary.-The police is searching the woods for the vanished girl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Look up** indicates that you assume

- what you are looking for exists
- you have a method of locating it

**Search** indicates that you assume

- what you are looking for may or may not exist
- you *may* have a method for locating *candidates*

That is, when I take a telephone index and I locate the number of a person based on his name, I am *looking up* the number. I assume it is there, I use my knowledge of how the index works, and I assume I will (quickly) find the information.

Now, if I want to know **if** a person's phone number is mentioned on the internet, I will perform a search. I can use the person's name, address, whatever I know about him. I can use key words like "phone" to help me. If I am lucky, I may find among all possible references the one that I am looking for.

In every-day life, we search more than we look up, I guess. We search for a car keys, we search for the meaning of life.

In the context of a form, the choice depends on what you want to tell the user:

> Give me exact data that will enable me to retrieve the data you are looking for.
> Give me some clues as to what you are looking for, and I will see what I can find for you.

In the first case, use **look up**; in the second case use **search**.

An addition based on Edwin Ashworth's comment (which, I have to say, I had to read several times to understand it :P ):

There is indeed another distinction. While you can both *search* for a phone number (you need *a* number to reach a help desk) or *look up* a phone number (you know hey help desk has a number, and you know where to look for it), there is something you can search and not look up:

You can **search** a database, or Google, or the internet - this doesn't mean you are looking for those things, you are looking for information contained at those locations!

If you have a good idea how to find what you are looking for, you can **look up** the information *in* the database, *on* the internet, etc.

Comment: This describes the different situations involved; NG's comment above states that the DO's (if 'search' is used with one) refer respectively to the places / resources where one might at least suspect the information might be found, and the information to be found.

Comment: I find these counterintuitive in my own perspective; perhaps this whole thing you say is, after all, correct, and I wasn't aware of that. Plus, there are no leads on "Further Reading" -- any help?

Comment: +1, and allow me to add another good way of demonstrating the difference:  If a ship is lost at sea, we send planes to search for it- we do not send planes to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

"search" is the French word "chercher" meaning to seek, to look for. When you use "to search" in English this implies that it takes time and that it is not so easy to find what you are looking for as in:

- The police are searching the woods for the vanished girl.